# Rails time is weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, time

```
<% if  post.created_at < 30.days.ago %>
  <%= post.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> 
<% else %>
  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
<% end%>
```

The post is created less than 30 days ago but the second condition runs. It is quiet weird and when i change the first line and make it `post.created_at > 30.days.ago` it returns the first condition even though it is false cause the posts were created far more earlier.

Please if anyone could explain why that is and what can i do to change it(if at all).

Comment: @MrYoshiji It didn't change anything. The output is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes sense in English:

> ```
> post.created_at < 30.days.ago
> ```

Your brain reads it as:

> If this post was created less than 30 days ago...

Ruby, however, reads it as:

> If the date this post was created is less than (before) the date 30 days ago...

Remember that `30.days.ago` returns a DateTime, not a duration. Let's suppose that `post.created_at` is two weeks ago, i.e. 2016-01-06 (it's actually a DateTime, but we'll disregard the time for the sake of demonstration). Two weeks is less than 30 days, so you might expect your expression to evaluate to `true`. However, `30.days.ago` returns the date 2015-12-22. Put those values into our expression (pseudocode now):

```
2016-01-06 < 2015-12-22
```

This evaluates to `false`, because the date on the left is *not* before (read: not less than) the date on the right.

In order to test whether `post.created_at` is after (read: greater than) `30.days.ago`, we have to turn the operator around:

```
if post.created_at > 30.days.ago
```

P.S. Another way to think about it is whether the date 30 days ago is before (less than) `post.created_at`. This is basically (if not exactly) equivalent:

```
if post.created_at > (DateTime.now - 30.days)
```

Or you could consider whether `post.created_at` is between `30.days.ago` and today:

```
if post.created_at.between?(30.days.ago, DateTime.now)
```

Or, whether the time elapsed since `post.created_at` is less than 30 days:

```
if (DateTime.now - post.created_at) < 30.days
```

(Note that whereas `30.days.ago` returns a DateTime, `30.days` returns a duration.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding how your condition works.

In this situation, the if statement succeeds if `date_1` is before `date_2`:

```
if date_1 < date_2
  # do something
end
```

In your code, the if statement succeeds if the post is created **before** 30 days ago.

What you probably want is it to be after 30 days ago?

Comment: The first condition says `if  post.created_at < 30.days.ago ` the post is created less than 30 days ago but that code doesn't run the else code runs.

Comment: That is not what the condition says. As Jon explains the condition says that post.created_at should be before (<) the moment in time defined as 30 days ago, ie the post was created over 30 days ago.